# why the 'pause' system-call always return -1?

Tags: c, system-calls

or, why can't we simply declare pause as:

```
#include <unistd.h>
void pause(void);
```

since the return value of pause is meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [man page of `pause`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/pause.2.html)

```
RETURN VALUE

   pause()  only  returns when a signal was caught and the signal-catching
   function returned.  In this case pause() returns -1, and errno  is  set
   to EINTR.
```

Every syscall which is interrupted is getting `EINTR` (or `ERESTART` in peculiar cases). I see no reason to make `pause` an exception!

Of course you are free to write `(void) pause ();` in your code to ignore the result.